# How to unmarshall repeated nested classes with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

How can I instruct JAXB to process this ?

**XML**

```
<root>
 <parent>
    <child id="1" name="foo" />
 </parent>
 <parent>
    <child id="3" name="foo2" />
 </parent>
 <parent>
    <child id="4" name="bar2" />
 </parent>
 <parent>
    <child id="2" name="bar" />
 </parent>
</root>
```

**Root.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {
   @XmlElement(name="parent/child")
   List<Child> allChildren;
}
```

This doesn't work ... allChildren is empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could change your model and do the following:

**Root**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
   @XmlElement(name="parent")
   List<Parent> allParents;
}
```

**Parent**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
   @XmlElement(name="child")
   List<Child> allChildren;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Is it possible to avoid the parent class ?

There are a couple of different ways to accomplish this:

**OPTION #1 - Any JAXB Implementation using XmlAdapter**

You could use an XmlAdapter to virtually add in the `Parent` class.

**ChildAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ChildAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ChildAdapter.Parent, Child> {

    public static class Parent {
        public Child child;
    }

    @Override
    public Parent marshal(Child v) throws Exception {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.child = v;
        return parent;
    }

    @Override
    public Child unmarshal(Parent v) throws Exception {
        return v.child;
    }

}
```

**Root**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to reference the `XmlAdapter`.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

   @XmlElement(name="parent")
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ChildAdapter.class)
   List<Child> allChildren;

}
```

**Child**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    @XmlAttribute
    String name;

}
```

**OPTION #2 - Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

If you are using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation then you could do the following (Note: I'm the MOXy lead):

**Root**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

   @XmlElement(name="parent")
   List<Child> allChildren;

}
```

**Child**

MOXy's `@XmlPath` annotation works pretty much the way you are trying to use the `@XmlElement` annotation in your post.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {

    @XmlPath("child/@id")
    int id;

    @XmlPath("child/@name")
    String name;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the parent class ?

Comment: +1 It's always reassuring when I independently come up with exactly the same solution as an acknowledged expert in the field :-)

Comment: @IanRoberts - I +1ed your answer as well :).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a class representing the `<parent>` element, such as

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
   @XmlElement(name="child")
   Child child;
}
```

You could then create a type adapter

```
public class ParentToChildAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Parent, Child> {
  public Parent marshal(Child c) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    p.child = child;
    return p;
  }

  public Child unmarshal(Parent p) {
    return p.child;
  }
}
```

and use this on the root class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {
   @XmlElement(name="parent")
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ParentToChildAdapter.class)
   List<Child> allChildren;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `XmlElementWrapper` annotation but I am not sure how it should work with multiple wrapper nodes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="parent")
   @XmlElement(name="child")
   List<Child> allChildren;
}
```

Comment: I get only one child and not all children.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@XmlRootElement
class Root {
    List<Child> allChildren = new ArrayList<Child>();

    private static class Parent  {
        @XmlElement
        Child child;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setParent(Parent p) {
        allChildren.add(p.child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes he did, but Parent here is just a trick, just a private class. Most importantly that we have List<Child> not List<Parent>