# JAXB - element value field

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class, that is something like this:

```
public class Property {

    private double floorArea;

    public double getFloorArea() {
        return floorArea;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setFloorArea(double floorArea) {
        this.floorArea = floorArea;
    }

}
```

Which will give me something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<property>
    <floorArea>x</floorArea>
</property>
```

But I need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<property>
    <floorArea>
        <value>x</value>
    </floorArea>
</property>
```

The API I am using requires it this way. My limited JAXB knowledge is preventing me from figuring this out. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

something I am researching. Would I need to create a `value` class with its own JAXB annotations for this to work? (and set `floorArea` to the type of `value`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB - Unmarshall repeated nested classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975632/jaxb-unmarshall-repeated-nested-classes)

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: In this case I think the connection with the method of solving the earlier question is not going to be as clear to this OP as it is to you.  Since the emphasis here is adding a nesting level to the emitted XML, rather than a nice way of capturing repeated elements, I'd say it's a near duplicate rather than an exact one.  jsn's EDIT suggests progress in the right direction, and I'm sure some encouragement would be appreciated!

Comment: @hardmath - I have now added an answer to this question that should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14101795/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: +1  As with all such detailed answers, the benefits will pass to readers long after the OP has gotten squared away.  Thanks for making the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is how your use case could be supported with an `XmlAdapter` using any JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.

**XmlAdapter (DoubleValueAdapter)**

An `XmlAdapter` is a mechanism that allows an object to be converted to another type of object .  Then it is the converted object that is converted to/from XML.

```
package forum14045961;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DoubleValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<DoubleValueAdapter.AdaptedDoubleValue, Double>{

    public static class AdaptedDoubleValue {
        public double value;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedDoubleValue marshal(Double value) throws Exception {
        AdaptedDoubleValue adaptedDoubleValue = new AdaptedDoubleValue();
        adaptedDoubleValue.value = value;
        return adaptedDoubleValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Double unmarshal(AdaptedDoubleValue adaptedDoubleValue) throws Exception {
        return adaptedDoubleValue.value;
    }

}
```

**Property**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to specify the `XmlAdapter`.  I needed to change `double` to `Double` so I moved the mapping to the field as to not affect the public API.

```
package forum14045961;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Property {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DoubleValueAdapter.class)
    private Double floorArea;

    public double getFloorArea() {
        return floorArea;
    }

    public void setFloorArea(double floorArea) {
        this.floorArea = floorArea;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code to prove that everything works.

```
package forum14045961;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Property.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14045961/input.xml");
        Property property = (Property) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(property, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

Below is the input to and output from the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<property>
    <floorArea>
        <value>1.23</value>
    </floorArea>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is how you could map your use case using MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension:

**Property**

```
package forum14045961;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
public class Property {

    private double floorArea;

    public double getFloorArea() {
        return floorArea;
    }

    @XmlPath("floorArea/value/text()")
    public void setFloorArea(double floorArea) {
        this.floorArea = floorArea;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

Only the standard JAXB runtime APIs are required to read the objects from and write them back to XML when MOXy is used as the JAXB provider.

```
package forum14045961;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Property.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14045961/input.xml");
        Property property = (Property) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(property, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

Below is the input to and output from running the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property>
   <floorArea>
      <value>1.23</value>
   </floorArea>
</property>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: I actually looked at MOXy and tried to use it, but the library was very large (in size) compared to the original JAXB library. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @jsn - We are currently refactoring MOXy so that it will have a much smaller jar.  If you follow me on Twitter http://twitter.com/bdoughan or through my blog http://blog.bdoughan.com you will see updates on its progress.

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch is correct the way described will generate the xml as you have displayed.

```
public class Property {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected FloorArea floorArea;
    public FloorArea getFloorArea() {
        return floorArea;
    }
    public void setFloorArea(FloorArea value) {
        this.floorArea = value;
    }
}
```

And your FloorArea class would look something like the code snapshot below.

```
public class FloorArea {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution. But it didn't work out. I wrote my own lightweight version of JAXB. Thanks.

Comment: @jsn - I have added 2 answers.  The first is how the idea from this answer could be hidden behind an `XmlAdapter` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14101795/383861).  The second leverages the `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14101682/383861)