# JAXB marshal unmarshal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a xml format like following

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C>
   <e></e>
   <f></f>
  </C>
 </B>
</A>
```

Earlier I used jox to covert bean to xml and had the following kind of bean structure

```
class ClassC{
 String e;
 String f;
}

class ClassB{
 ClassC C;
}

class A{ 
 ClassB B;
}
```

And now I want to use JAXB for marshal and unmarshal such beans and xml strings. Is there a way to omit **ClassB** and still get the same xml structure I have given above with JAXB.

Comment: I think I found the answer in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975632/how-to-unmarshall-repeated-nested-classes-with-jaxb . But I'm still curious if there are any changes to the Jaxb implementation since then to support this kind of behavior?

Comment: The answers to the question you linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975632/how-to-unmarshall-repeated-nested-classes-with-jaxb) are still appropriate today.