# JAXB: The attribute name is undefined for the annotation type XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

When I attempt to assign the `name` attribute for an `XmlElement` for JAXB, I get the error in Eclipse:

```
The attribute name is undefined for the annotation type XmlElement
```

Example of my model class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Components {

    Component component;

    @XmlElement(name = "component")  // error on this line
    public void setComponent(Component component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975735/2386187).

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, it turns out it was a dumb mistake. I was importing

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.annotation.XmlElement;
```

instead of

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
```